# How to properly use a has_many :through with an alias_method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2. I have following associations with an `alias_method` used for a `has_many :through` association, this way:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_associations
  alias_method :post_associations, :article_associations

  has_many :users, :through => :post_associations
end
```

When I execute the `@article.users` I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError
Could not find the association :post_associations in model Article
```

Why it happens? Is there a way to make it to work as expected? That is, how to properly return `@article.users` through the "aliased" `:post_associations`?

---

*Note*: I would like to "state" / "use" the `:post_associations` in the `has_many :users, :through => :post_associations` statement because I am trying to "dynamically build" (that is, metaprogramming) the `has_many :through` association.

---

The Ruby on Rails *Framework Trace* is:

```
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:501:in `check_validity!'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:26:in `initialize'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:24:in `initialize'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:10:in `initialize'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `new'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `association'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:44:in `block in define_readers'
...
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to alias your association? I don't think there is a way to easily achieve an association alias so it would help to understand what you need to help you workaround this limitation.

Comment: @Vincent Robert _ It is because I am trying to abstract the article as a post within a Mixin module. That is, I would like that in the Mixin module the article is considered a posts, at all. Since that, I would like to `alias_method :post_associations, :article_associations` even for associations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason why you need to alias_method name your association.

Instead you could directly do something like this,

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_associations, :foreign_key => :resource_id, :class_name => "ArticleAssociation"
  has_many :users, :through => :post_associations
end
```

**Another Solution**

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_associations
  has_many :users, :through => :article_associations
end

def post_associations
  self.article_associations
end
```

you need to do either of this

```
resource.post_associations
```

or

```
resource.article_associations
```

Comment: I explained the "reason why I need to `alias_method` name my association" in response to the @Vincent Robert's comment to the question.

Comment: If you need to do this, try adding a method called post_associations and called this method on a resource object, the definition would in turn be calling article_associations only.

Comment: I didn't understand at all. Can you be more explicit (maybe with an example)?

Comment: I have added an alternate solution

Comment: I seen your answer. Thank you, but I need to "state" / "use" that in the `has_many :users, :through => :post_associations` statement (as explained in the question). It is because I would "dynamically build" (metaprogramming) the `has_many :through` association.

Comment: Ok, I get it, I don't think there is a way to alias the association names

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to achieve [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: No, I am not trying to achieve polymorphic associations. I do not really need that.